# Retrofit2: How to get binary file inside response body

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I get data from a web service that sends files in binary format inside response body. I want to get that binary data.
I'm not gonna write the whole log here because it's too long and it's not helpful but i'm gonna write the first few lines:
The first line of the PDF is this: `%PDF-1.4` and the rest is binary characters like this: `��Yi3y�H�w��L�A���mCvÆ��.��K��7����Z0�VP`. so it's a PDF file inside response body.

And here's my code to get it:

```
@Streaming
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
@POST("/auto/report/download")
Call<String> sendStatementDownloadRequest(@Body DepositStatementsDownloadRequest request);
```

And this is how i call it:

```
webservice.sendStatementDownloadRequest(request).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.i("VVV", "onResponse: " + new Gson().toJson(response));
                } else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

The problem is it only gets the first line which is this: `%PDF-1.4` and skip the rest of it which is the binary data.
is there anyway to get the whole body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call for a `ResponseBody` object instead of `String`

Your call should be like this

```
   @Streaming
   @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept:     application/json"})
   @POST("/auto/report/download")
   Call<ResponseBody> sendStatementDownloadRequest(@Body   DepositStatementsDownloadRequest request);
```

Comment: How to get the body as string? or should i get it as a string?

Comment: call for a responsebody then convert it to string.. `responsebody.toString();`